# Samba: Share directory with a specific Windows 10 user without password required

Tags: permissions, password, samba, windows-10, username

I would like instructions for creating a Samba share that can only be accessed by a specific Windows 10 user without a password required.

I have read some tutorials and, while I can easily create a share that anyone can access, I have not been able to create one that only the specific user can access. I can see the directory in question but if I try to open it, I get an Access Denied error and Windows File Explorer asks for a username and password.

I did create a linux user with what I believe to be the username on the Windows PC and the same password as the Windows user. If I type the credentials of this Linux user I created into the prompt mentioned above, I am granted access. All I can think of at this point is that the username of the Linux account is not the same as the corresponding Windows account.

Here is what I have in smb.conf

```
encrypt passwords = yes
security = user

[Email Backup]
    comment = email backup folder
    path = /home/samba/emailbackup
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = xavie emailer +emailbackup
```

`xavie` is the name of the Linux account that is supposed to correspond with the Windows account, `emailer` is another Linux account that needs access to the directory and `emailbackup` is a group the the two accounts are both members of. The Windows account is a Microsoft account (ie. not a local account; tied to an @Outlook.com email address) if that changes anything.

If this problem is caused by the wrong username, can anyone advise me on how I can find the username that needs to be assigned to the Linux account (eg. is there a log file I can look at to see what user tried to gain access to the Samba share)? Otherwise, is there anything else I can check that might be the cause of this problem?

**EDIT:**
I have done some searching on the internet and have made some progress. After examining Samba's log files, I found that I was correct in believing that the username was incorrect. According to the log files, Windows 10, when the user uses a Microsoft account, identifies the user to Samba with the email address used by that account rather than the username. Here is the log (level 2) that I was seeing:

```
[2016/08/20 14:15:36.349641,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2700(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[All Users]"
[2016/08/20 14:15:36.349966,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2700(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Email Backup]"
[2016/08/20 14:15:36.350850,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [<snip email address>] -> [<snip email address>] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
```

I added the email address to the smbuser file associating it with the Linux account I created. This worked and the log now says that I successfully authenticate but I now have a new problem.

The new problem is that Samba sharing doesn't work at all for my PC when logged into the account I noted above. Basically, I have two shares on my Ubuntu server; a public share that anyone can access and the other share that I want accessible only to the Windows 10 user. That Windows 10 user, after I made the above changes, can now no longer see either of the shares or even access the Ubuntu server. OTOH, my father's laptop, which doesn't have an account on Samba, can access the server and see both shares (but can't access the non-public share without authentication). Here is the new log created with the changes to smbusers:

```
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.523779,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2700(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[All Users]"
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.524358,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2700(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Email Backup]"
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.552274,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:305(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [<snip email address>] -> [xavie] -> [xavie] succeeded
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.553509,  1] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2389(lp_idmap_range)
  idmap range not specified for domain '*'
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.553782,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:430(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-1934213540-918117097-1557597498-1000 -> getpwuid(1002) failed
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.554723,  1] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2389(lp_idmap_range)
  idmap range not specified for domain '*'
[2016/08/20 14:36:44.554938,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:430(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-1934213540-918117097-1557597498-1000 -> getpwuid(1002) failed
```

Here are the current contents of smb.conf, if it helps anyone. I'm only including what I changed though; anything not mentioned is at default:

```
[global]
  log level = 2
  username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
  encrypt passwords = yes
  security = user    

[All Users]
    comment = Directory accessible to all users
    path = /home/samba/allusers
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777

[Email Backup]
    comment = email backup folder
    path = /home/samba/emailbackup
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    valid users = xavie emailer +emailbackup
```

Can anyone see what the new problem I'm having is?

Help will be greatly appreciated,
Kind regards

Comment: What does `echo %USERNAME%` say on that Windows 10 machine?  That should be the username. 

Also, if you do set up a `guest ok` share, you don't need to specify the users at all, since everyone has access.  It's been ages I needed to set up something like that and the clients were XP back then.

A quick Google gives me this:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Anonymous_Share

Sounds like what you need.  Notice the `global` settings?  When I first tried, that was the little detail, I was missing.

Comment: What happens in that scenario (wiki article).  Basically `map to guest = Bad user`, means as much as "hey, if you have an invalid user, map it to the following account".  That is set in the following line under `guest user`. They use nobody, but if you prefer you can use any user you want.  Up to you.  So, now Samba knows how what to do with bad users, which is "treat them as a guest, named nobody" (in the example)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to solve the authentication problem but encountered a new problem. Please do read the edit I made. `echo %USERNAME%` in Windows 10 returns `xavie` but as I noted in my edit, Windows 10 is passing the email address of my Microsoft account to Samba rather than this username. I could create shares that everyone has access to but unfortunately, this is not what I want in this case. My situtation would be a lot easier if I could simply configure this Samba share in this way.

Comment: Well, most sensible people avoid locking their Windows computers to their online accounts.  I've seen many problems caused by it.  Off to reading what you wrote, but I remember there is a user mapping functionality in Samba.  Just like the bad user thing, but for other input.  Off to reading what you wrote.

Comment: This would be the mapping feature: http://www.linuceum.com/Server/srvSambaUserMap.php

Comment: Or with an external file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/269643/how-do-i-map-users-with-a-samba-share

Comment: Never mind, I see that in your config.  I assume you did the email -> user mapping in there and not by adding the email to the smbpasswd database.

Comment: Wait.  Have you created the samba user?  Creating a Unix user is not enough.  When you have done that, you must also create a samba user with `smbpasswd`.  That is where the password for Samba is stored.  For all intents and purposes you can make the Unix user nologin without password, as long as it's also in the Samba password file with password.
So, unless you did do this:  `sudo mbpasswd -a xavie`.
This is because Unix and Windows use different methods to store their password, but they both are different hashes.

Comment: "See" as in "see in the interface", or even unable to connect with `net use`.  If it's "seeing in the interface", make sure that the workgroups match.  Windows is picky about that.
Direct connection using \\yourserver\desireshare should still work.

Comment: I've managed to fix the second problem by myself. I don't know how I did it exactly but I just deleted the Samba and Linux accounts then recreated them. After I did that, the Samba share worked. The `Email Backup` share is now accessible from my Windows 10 account without a password whereas other users are denied access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to figure out how to make what I requested work and will post the instructions.

1. First, you need to figure out what the username you need to add is. The easiest way to do this is to first add `log level = 2` to `smb.conf`. Then start and enable the Samba service. Then connect to the Samba server using File Explorer on the Windows PC while logged into the relevant account (you don't have to open any shared directories). Then open the log file found at `/var/log/samba/log.<ip address of Windows PC>` and the required username will be noted there. You can now set log level to 0 if you want.
2. Create a Linux account for the Samba user using the `useradd` command (or use an existing one if you prefer). You don't need to worry about passwords with this account but if you create a new account, you may want to block login on it. This account's username doesn't have to be the same as the name noted above but it would be easier if it was. This account's purpose is for the purpose of file permissions and for Linux to determine what files and directories the Windows user is allowed to access.
3. Create a Samba user with the same name as the Linux account in step 2 using the `smbpasswd` command. Make sure the password assigned to this account is the same as the one used for the Windows account.
4. If the Samba and Windows accounts don't share the same username, you will have to either add `!<Samba user> = <Windows user>` to `smb.conf` or add `<Samba user> = <Windows user>` to `smbusers` and `username map = /etc/samba/smbusers` to `smb.conf`.
5. And that should be it. Be sure to set the `valid users =` option on any shares you want accessible only by your Windows account.