# Find owner of a file in SMB mounted NAS storage

Tags: permissions, samba, nas

I have access to a NAS storage server along with many others. Everyone has their own login credentials to NAS which is mounted using SMB.

Now, lets assume the username of my Ubuntu PC is 'abc' and the username of NAS login is 'xyz'. From the terminal, after `cd` to the NAS storage mount, I decided to check the list of files and find whos owners are.

```
-rwx------ 1 abc abc 350 Dec  8 15:15 1.lst
drwx------ 1 abc abc   0 Dec 11 15:53 2
```

Now, I tried the same steps from another computer with a username 'def'. This is what I got:

```
-rwx------ 1 def def 350 Dec  8 15:15 1.lst
drwx------ 1 def def   0 Dec 11 15:53 2
```

Why is the username shown as that of the person who is viewing the files? I expect it to show the names of users who had created the files. If I am doing it wrong, please help me in finding the real owners of each of the files and folders in a network shared harddrive.

Comment: Sounds like the server is mapping all authenticated network users to the same local user. Do you have access to the NAS? Does it have a usernamemap section in /etc/samba/smb.conf? If not you're probably out of luck. See this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/269643/how-do-i-map-users-with-a-samba-share and this link http://www.linuceum.com/Server/srvSambaUserMap.php

Comment: Is there a way to not manually map them, but instead show the info stored with the file on the ownership? Will using some other option to mout other than SMB help in solving this issue?

Comment: If we can't track on who created a particular file, whats the intend of the NAS settings supporting multiple login users?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable unix extensions to see the original owner of a file. Edit the SMB config file of the server:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

And add this to your global rules:

```
unix extensions = yes
```

But note: Although its not mentioned [in the documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS), this works only if you force SMB1 (NT1), so you need to add this as well:

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

And if you mount your server, you need to force SMB1 as follows:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/smbserver/sharename
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=john,vers=1.0 //servername/sharename /mnt/smbserver/sharename
```

After that you will see the original linux owner of the file.

But note this as well: It transfers only the uid and not the name of the user. If the file owner has the uid 1234 and your linux client does not have any user with this uid, it will show only the number:

```
client$ ls -la /mnt/smbserver/sharename
total 4
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 root root     0 Sep 11 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Nov 13 18:05 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 1234 users    0 Okt 31 21:20 paper
drwxrwx---+ 1 1234 users    0 Okt 30 09:43 vanilla
```

And if you linked the client's username "test" to the uid 1234, it will show "test" as the file owner:

```
client$ ls -la /mnt/smbserver/sharename
total 4
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 root root     0 Sep 11 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Nov 13 18:05 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 test users    0 Okt 31 21:20 paper
drwxrwx---+ 1 test users    0 Okt 30 09:43 vanilla
```

although it could be a different username on the server:

```
smbserver$ ls -la /home/john/sharename
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Sep 11 22:22 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 john users 4096 Nov 10 19:13 ../
drwxrwx--- 1 john users 4096 Nov 13 19:23 paper/
drwxrwx--- 1 john users 4096 Oct 30 11:43 vanilla/
```

So the best would be to have identical usernames and uids on all systems.